# Recording US election sound effects - suggestions?

Tags: field-recording, suggestions, sound-effects

Hi everyone,

I'm considering recording US election sound effects this fall.  I heard that there were some great reactions after the 2008 elections and would love to record those sort of sounds.

I want to capture the general experience via sound before, during and after the election.

My idea is to record at polling stations and galas, catch chatter, reactions afterwards, etc.  Basically the spirit and the hopes and disappointments.

Since I'm not American, I'm wondering if any of you have suggestions.

Beyond crowds, reactions, etc., any ideas what to record?

Where should I be?  Outside the White House?  Are there particular Democratic or Republican strongholds?  Is it best to hang around the Democratic or Republican headquarters in Washington?  Since we don't know who will win I'm thinking the best location would have potential for both Republican and Democratic enthusiastic crowds.

I'm open to travelling anywhere in the US, so location doesn't matter.

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Paul Virostek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're going to find is that most Americans generally dislike everything leading up to the elections. Posturing for the Republican nomination has been going on in a very media-loud way for well over a year now, and most of us are sick of it. Your best bet is going to be finding people who are still invested in/enthusiastic about the elections. That means your only hope is getting in with groups who are actively campaigning for one party or the other. The next big events are the RNC and DNC (Republican and Democrat national conventions). Those are going to be the "kick-off" parties. I don't know what will be happening at the White House on the day of the elections (which is sad considering I live a mere 11 miles away from it), but I'm sure something will happen (general public, maybe protests, etc...probably nothing official). You're on the right track with the galas. At polling stations, you may find people campaigning for one side or the other (or both)...most other people will probably be interested in just getting in and back out. Those volunteer and paid campaign groups are probably going to be your best options for getting reactions out of people.

If you do come to the DC area though, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Shaun!  Some great ideas.  Very informative about what actually happens at that time.  I think the idea of going for the enthusiastic extremes is the way to go.  I will definitely let you know if I make it to DC!  Cheers! Paul